# TaskKill ONLY a cmd.exe child process with batchfile

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to close a cmd.exe child process. I already tried using /f and /im but it doesn't work.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Please copy and paste the command and the output into the question.

Comment: Edit your question and post your code !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to kill the process by the Process-ID (PID).
Type:

> tasklist

in cmd and look for the PID of the child process you want to close or look in task manager. 
If you have the correct PID you can use e.g.:

> taskkill /pid 2292

to close the process (child process) using this ID. 
You also can close multiple PIDs at same time by using the command like:

> taskkill /pid 2292 /pid 2232

Hope this will help you :-)